# Programatic dependency specification in a plugin

Tags: gradle

In a multi project build I can declare a dependency on another build in a subproject build.gradle file as

```
project compile(':projectA')
```

which I can translate into the following in a plugin

```
project.dependencies.add("compile", project.parent.findProject("projectA"))
```

If I want to specify a configuration on the dependency in the build.gradle I can use

```
compile project(path: ':projectA', configuration: 'testUtilRuntime')
```

but I cannot work out how to specify this in a plugin. Please help.

I tried using a DefaultProjectDependencyFactory.create(), amongst other things, but that expects a ProjectInternal and the findProject returns a DefaultProject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean `dependencies { compile project(":projectA") }`, which translates to `project.dependencies { compile project.project(":projectA") }` in a (Groovy) plugin. The second snippet translates to `project.dependencies { compile project(path: ':projectA', configuration: 'testUtilRuntime') }`. Here the inner `project` doesn't need to be qualified because it refers to `DependencyHandler#project` rather than `Project#project`.

Comment: With your project.dependencies { compile project(path: ':projectA', configuration: 'testUtilRuntime') }
I get the following
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':projectB'.
> Could not find method call() for arguments [{path=:projectA, configuration=testUtilRuntime}] on project ':projectB'.

Comment: and putting project.project on there hangs Gradle when evaluating the projects.

This is Gradle 1.6, I am a little stuck with that version at the moment because of the red tape in bringing in software

Comment: Putting `project.project` there can't work as you need to call `DependencyHandler#project`, not `Project#project`. If `project` alone doesn't work, then maybe due to your other code (e.g. you might already have a local variable named `project`). To be on the safe side, use full qualification (`project.dependencies.project`).

Comment: Ah yes, I do have a local variable named project, putting project.dependencies.project works.